# Redis as a session store in glassfish

Tags: session, glassfish, redis, memcached, high-availability

I got an open-source component called tomcat-redis-session-manager can store http session in redis, to provide high-availability in many tomcat servers.
So I want to find if there is a way to store glassfish http session in redis or memcached.
But I have not find what is the http session creation or acquire interceptor in glassfish.
Can anyone tell me how?

Tomcat does it by adding the following in context.xml

```
<Valve className="com.radiadesign.catalina.session.RedisSessionHandlerValve" />
<Manager className="com.radiadesign.catalina.session.RedisSessionManager"
host="localhost"
port="6379"
database="0"
maxInactiveInterval="60"
/>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for offloading Glassfish http sessions to some other persistence (be it in-memory or datastore)?